# Java Swing basic animation issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent, repaint

I've just started learning GUI's and Swing, and decided to write a program I found in a textbook to display a coloured rectangle and make it look like it's decreasing in size on the screen.

Below is the code I have written, my issue is that the rectangle displays on the screen, but is not repainted to a smaller size every 50ms. Can anyone point out where i'm going wrong with this?

Many thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Animate {

int x = 1;
int y = 1;

public static void main(String[] args){

    Animate gui = new Animate();
    gui.start();

}

public void start(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Rectangles rectangles = new Rectangles();

    frame.getContentPane().add(rectangles);
    frame.setSize(500,270);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++,y++,x++){

        x++;
        rectangles.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}





class Rectangles extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 500-x*2, 250-y*2);
}

}
}
```

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging? Did you add a statement to your paint method to see if it is being invoked? Did you display the values of x/y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the rectangle displays on the screen, but is not repainted to a smaller size every 50ms

When doing custom painting the basic code should be:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g); // to clear the background

    //  add custom painting code
}
```

If you don't clear the background then the old painting remains. So painting something smaller will not make a difference.

For a better structure of your code the x/y variables should be defined in the `Rectangles` class. Then you should create a method like `decreaseSize()` which is also defined in your `Rectangles` class. This code will update the x/y values and then invoke repaint on itself. So your animation code will just invoke the `decreaseSize()` method.

Comment: That makes complete sense now, thanks. I will try creating the method you suggested

Answer (score 0):

1. You should repaint the whole `JFrame` instead (or the JPanel your graphics are on).
2. You don't have to call `x++` twice, instead do `x+=2`

Change your code to this (works, I also fixed the indentation):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Animate {

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animate gui = new Animate();
        gui.start();

    }

    public void start() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Rectangles rectangles = new Rectangles();

        frame.getContentPane().add(rectangles);
        frame.setSize(500, 270);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++, y++, x += 2) {
            frame.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    class Rectangles extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 500 - x * 2, 250 - y * 2);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no reason to repaint the entire frame. If only the panel changes, then just repaint the panel. 2) Good advice, but the posted code is not executing on the EDT. Code executed from the main method is invoked on a normal thread UNLESS, the code is wrapped in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Comment: @camickr He didn't create a JPanel, he added everything to the contentpane of the JFrame. (but thanks for pointing out that my statement wasn't correct (same for point 2)).